# How to get a string of the Title values of a 2D array in Jquery using $.each?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

```
<script>
var array = [
{"ID":1, "Title":'abc'},
{"ID":2, "Title":'pqr'},
{"ID":3, "Title":'xyz'}
];
function arrayFunction(key,value){
var str ="";
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
value=array[i].Title;
str=str + ";" + value;
}
alert(str);
}
</script>
```

It is running properly.Now,I want the output as abc;pqr;xyz using $.each.

Comment: are you sure it's `var array = {...}` instead of `var array = [...]`?

Comment: This is neither a valid object nor array.

Comment: anyhow, I suggest you read up on Array.prototype.map(), once you figure out how your 2D array really looks.

Comment: Please provide a working [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.reduce:

```js
var array= [
{"ID":1, "Title":"abc"},
{"ID":2, "Title":"pqr"},
{"ID":3, "Title":"xyz"}
];
var str = array.reduce((m, o) => m + o.Title + ';', "");
console.log(str);
```